# How do I connect my online store to the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, api

I have an online store for which I want to be able to accept bitcoin.

I believe that what I need is an API that will connect my store to the blockchain. If not, the question below would relate to what I need.

I need a developer who can handle both ends of the project, that is identifying or building the right API to connect to the blockchain, and connecting the API to my storefront. How would I find the right application and a reasonably good developer?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to accept payment by Bitcoin or Bitcoin API in your application then you can use "blockchain.com" 's API in your application. So that you can build function and module as per your requirement and also if you want to build your eCommerce platform from scratch then you can use "CryptoWoo.com".

Answer (score 2):

Hard Solutions would be building your payment system from scratch e.g. generating bitcoin addresses and checking them for payments and then confirm the order.

but if you don't want to get your hands dirty then you may use some third parties such as blockchain.info.

the problem with third parties is stability. blockchain.info is free and has a nice API.

Answer (score 1):

The other suggestions already cover a couple of providers with API's.

Much of what will need to be done depends on your storefront frontend/backend. For example, if you use CubeCart there are payment gateway extensions, some of which *may* enable Bitcoin. (I am not affiliated with any)

https://www.cubecart.com/extensions/payment-gateways

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'put your store on the blockchain' and 'accept bitcoin', these are two different (but closely related) goals.

In order for your store to accept bitcoin, it is as simple as setting up a particular payment processor which will accept/convert bitcoin, such as coinbase.com (very popular).

In order to 'put your store on the blockchain', this is an entirely different beast than the former (bitcoin) concern.

By applying the principles of decentralization/triple ledger accounting, you are fundamentally shifting the way that your business operates.

Also you must decide the extent you would like to decentralize: You can have a web 3.0 store-front which asks very much like a traditional e-commerce platform (while accepting bitcoin), you can create smart contracts to automatically fulfill orders when purchased with bitcoin, you can decentralize the principles behind your supply chain, and much more.